# Run script after view is loaded AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im new at AngularJS, and i have this problem;

I fill part of my view with html from a variable in my controller:

```
<div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"></div>
```

Everything goes fine until i decide to run a script. The script is shown, but it doesn't run. I think the problem is the view is filled with my variable controllers after loading the page, so the script doesn't run. 
The reason that i am using a variable in my controller to storage the script is because i will have to get the script from somewhere else, and its frequently changed.

Is this a viable way to run my script?.

Here is an example of my code:

**View:**

```
    <div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"></div>
```

**Controller:**

```
    .controller('browseCtrl', function($scope,$sce) {

      $scope.video = '<div id="idxx1" style="width: 460px; height: 290px;" itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject"></div><script>addeere3ejs("idxx1",  "172653", "24431581", "1_fq2w6oc2");</script>';

      $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function() {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.video);
    };
})
```

If my question it is unclear i would try to explain it better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the viewContentLoaded event in your controller.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
 // Run after view loaded.
});
```

Not exactly sure if ng-bind-html will allow a script to be ran like that. You may need to wrap it in angulars brackets to auto-run on load.

```
 <div ng-bind-html="{{deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()}}"></div>
```

Comment: This may be tied to ui-router, I'm unsure.

Comment: It's not, it should be available in a vanilla AngularJS application. However, I still don't think this answers the question.

Comment: Edited my answer, giving both examples.

Comment: I resolved the problem adding the function addeere3ejs(foo, foo, etc) in my controller. So i could manipulate it's execution more easily. Thanks @ChristopherMarshall for helping.

Answer (score 0):

My work around was to run a $scope function like this with a known variable(s) that will change:

```html
{{postBind(results)}}
```

Then have a method in your controller to do this

```
$scope.postBind = function (obj) {
        running_my_extenal_methods();
    }
```